# How to install drivers for speakers

Tags: drivers, sound

I have installed elementaryOS on my Huawei Matebook D. This laptop has a Dolby Atmos Audio-Soundsystem with 4 speakers. 
With the Linux installation, the speakers are much quieter and sound much worse.

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the Matebook Pro X and had the same issue. In my case only two of the four speakers worked (bottom worked top didn't) after installing elementary OS and a few other distros. I was able to find information that allowed me to get get the top two speakers working and now it sounds great. If your top two speakers are not working this may apply to the Matebook D as well.

1. In a terminal install some audio packages

`sudo apt install alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui pavucontrol`

2. In the terminal run the hdajackretask utility

`hdajackretask`

3. Once the GUI opens choose "Realtek ALC256" in the "Selecta a codec" dropdown

[image]

4. Check the "Show unconnected pins" and "Advanced override" boxes under "Options"

[image]

5. You should see a list of pins under "Pin configuration" with identifiers like "Pin ID: 0x14". You will need to override two of them, "0x14" and "0x1b". Check the "Override" box on both of them and set all of the values as shown below.

[image]

And

[image]

6. Click "Apply now" and test the speakers. If they work click on "Install boot override"
7. Rebuild your initramfs with the command below then reboot

`sudo update-initramfs -u`

8. After rebooting, open the PulseAudio Volume Control application (pavucontrol) and make sure that the window is wide enough to see the "Configuration" tab (or use the > button to scroll right). Click "Configuration" then choose "Analog Surround 4.0 Output" in the "Profile" dropdown. You can hear the difference by playing a good song and switching between "Analog Stereo Duplex" and "Analog Surround 4.0 Output".